# PHP exec() called via web vs CLI

Tags: php, web, exec, command-line-interface

I'm trying to use exec() in PHP and i get different results when using it through a web browser and via the command line shell.

simple thing:

`<?php exec('mount 10.0.0.1:/mnt/test /home/user/test', $output) ?>`

calling this from a web browser results in nothing being mounted and running it through the command line (php-cli) results in the mount being executed successfully.
there are also no errors being returned to the $output array. So I haven't got anything to go by.
I'm running the web and cli both as the same user, so it shouldn't be a permissions problem. SElinux is disabled and therefore doesn't block anything. Same thing for the firewall - disabled as well.

How can I make PHP exec() behave the same way in a web browser and via command line?

Comment: Make sure that the username under which your web server runs has sufficient permissions.

Comment: i pretty much gave full permissions to that user. ran the same PHP script from the command line as that user and it works just fine. So i'm a bit baffled. Is there a setting in Apache that prevents certain commands? I can run 'mount' by itself and it does show me all the current mounts through the web. Just can't mount any drive when calling that PHP scripts through the web.

Comment: How are you running the web script as a particular user?

Comment: I assume it runs as the user set for Apache in httpd.conf. which is the same user that I user to run the script at the command line. I can even run <?php exec('sudo mount ....') ?> with the same results. So it doesn't quite make sense to me

Comment: @user1730601 Maybe that's a $PATH problem? Try exec('/path/to/mount ... ')

Comment: The $PATH variable should not be a problem since I can run mount by itself without any options and I do get the current mounts returned

Answer (score 0):

You can only mount partitions as root, maybe adding www-data (I'm assuming that's the user running apache) to sudoers will solve the problem but it gives you a BIG security hole. But since you cannot write a password because it's a service, you have to tell not to ask a password to that user.

Add this to the bottom of your sudoers:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And use the command as

```
<?php exec('sudo mount 10.0.0.1:/mnt/test /home/user/test', $output) ?>
```

**Obviously this is a security hole like no other has ever been.**

One way to avoid it might be to use a queue to put the job and process it with a service that verifies the job is safe and mounts if it has to.

A nice queue that has a php interface is [beanstalk](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/)